How does Delegated OnlineMeetingRecording.Read.All work?
There is an OnlineMeetingRecording.Read.All permission in Microsoft Azure. I have added a delegated OnlineMeetingRecording.Read.All permission for an app's API Permission which says Read all recordings of online meetings. in the description.
Does this permission allow access to all Meeting recordings or just for a specific user? I mean would it be possible to fetch recording of a meeting whose creator has not consented?
(whose refresh token we use to fetch a meeting).
Also, why is there no OnlineMeetingRecording.Read permission?

I don't know about this specific permission, but in general delegated permissions should not give any more access than what the user has. So if the user can read recordings made by someone else, then the app might be able to as well.

What do you mean by "if the user can read recordings made by someone else". When can a user read recordings made by someone else ?

I don't know :P If they can't, then the app should not be able to either.

ok .. been stuck in this for some time. Couldn't find the answer in the docs.


Note that: OnlineMeetingRecording.Read.All permission works only for the signed in user and if the user is part of the meeting.


It will throw a 403 error if the user is not part of the meeting.

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onlineMeetings/MeetingID/recordings


When the other user tried to access the recording got the error:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onlineMeetings/MeetingID/recordings


